# GRUB2 Terminal: Ubuntu 23.10 does not boot, MX Linux 23.2 on Live-USB does not boot, too - commands?

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, mx-linux

I have some trouble with a "simple" boot or installation procedure.

1.
I would like to boot my Ubuntu, but I do not find the right command words doing it (hd0, fat or ext*).

2.
As safety mechanism I would like to boot MX Linux from an external USB stick (cd0, iso9660).

! both possibilities failed !

It is only possible to boot from a Grub2-terminal in every case.

Any ideas, I need support in this case.

Which informations do you need from my side to give the right "insmod"-commands?

A whole command word for the boot procedure from USB would be nice.

[image: Screen_1]

Comment: First, please run the `set` command in the `grub>` prompt. It should output a number of GRUB variables and their values. What are the values of `boot=` and `grub_platform=`? And `shim-lock=`, if it exists? The answers to these should help us identify from which device your current GRUB is starting on, verify the boot mode (UEFI vs. legacy) and whether Secure Boot is active or not.

Comment: After that, please run `ls (hd0,gpt2)/boot/` and `ls (cd0)/boot/` and show the outputs. These outputs should help in identifying the commands needed to boot either Ubuntu or MX Linux. Since your previous `ls` commands indicate the system already can read both of those filesystems, it is possible that no `insmod` commands are needed at all.

Comment: (1) I do not see a boot or shim-lock value there. In an earlier view The shim-lock value was 'y'. The grub_platform value is efi . Boot Mode should be UEFI. Secure Boot ist disabled.

Comment: (2) ls (hd0,gpt2)/boot/ - shows efi/   -   ls (cd0)/boot/ - shows grub/ isolinux/ memtest syslinux/ uefi-mt/

Comment: This is a repeat question.  I attempted to help Friday and the OP refused to recreate the bootable USB.  Today's question just adds Ubuntu.  In an effort not to discount this as a duplicate, please add your laptop model and your brand of UEFI Firmware brand and version

Answer (score 2):

Your current GRUB seems to be started from external media.

The fact that your `ls (hd0,gpt2)/boot/` shows just the `efi/` directory suggests your Ubuntu installation has no correctly installed kernel packages at all at this time. There should be at least one `vmlinuz-<version number>` and a corresponding `initrd.img-<version number>` in there.

That would certainly explain why Ubuntu is failing to boot - did you run out of space on the root filesystem when installing Ubuntu or making a major update? Normally the package manager will display very loud warnings if you try to remove the kernel the system is currently using, but during an installation or major release upgrade things might be different.

To boot your MX Linux, the following commands should do it:

```
set root=(cd0)
linux /antiX/vmlinuz quiet splasht nosplash 
initrd /antiX/initrd.gz
boot
```

If necessary, you could add more kernel boot options to the `linux ...` line.

I downloaded the MX Linux 23.2 ISO and investigated it to find the set of commands above. The GRUB configuration scheme of MX Linux seems very "German Engineering": very complex, trying to be automated and helpful, but as a result, ends up being not as resilient against faults and unexpected situations as it could otherwise be?

Comment: As I told him Friday, I don't think the image is being correctly burned to his USB.  He refused to burn the image using the links I gave.  He's since deleted that question , and rewritten this one.  Thanks

Comment: It does not work - error: invalid magic number.

Comment: It seems eyoung100 above is correct: your boot media appears corrupted.Redownload, [verify correctness of the download](https://mxlinux.org/wiki/system/iso-download-mirrors/#checksumsignatures), then rewrite your boot media.